# What are words that describe "the people" in the same way that "the machine" describes the ruling class?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

The powerful ruling class has been described as "the machine", "the man", "patricians", "the establishment", and "big brother". I am looking for similar words to describe the 99%, aka the plebeians (and more specifically the proletariat).

Comment: Are you looking for words the members of this group use to describe themselves, or words the ruling class use to describe them?  It makes a huge difference.

Comment: That is a good question. Both are interesting and equally important to be honest.

Comment: What is missing or not the right fit about the examples in your question? "the people", "the 99%", "the plebians", "the proletariat"? What characteristic(s) are you looking for which these lack?

Comment: I have never heard "the machine" used for the upper class, the powers that be.

Comment: @MrLister Heard this one? [Pink Floyd - Welcome To The Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt-udg9zQSE)

Comment: @DCShannon I will have to listen to that one again, more carefully this time.

Comment: What's wrong with proletariat? Anyway, since I am one of them, I like "taxpayers" or "voters". Because the one can only exist with the other.

Comment: The *worker bee*.

Answer (score 50):

The ***masses***.

Credit to [Emma Lazarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Colossus):

> "Keep, ancient lands, your storied pomp!" cries she
>   With silent lips. "Give me your tired, your poor,
>   Your huddled *masses* yearning to breathe free,

Comment: This is best. Some variations; the: _commoners_, _workers_, _underclass_, _hoi polloi_, _many_.

Comment: Oooh... "The Machine and The Masses". I don't know if thats a book, band, or album, but I want it.

Comment: Also the _unwashed masses_, more derogatorily.

Comment: "downtrodden masses" is another common, colourful pairing.

Answer (score 20):

With reference to a "machine", it would seem "cogs" would indicate serving an inferior function.

Comment: This could be a good one, though you should be careful to avoid a confusing metaphor since cogs are contained within a machine. It may suit your purposes but fits less well when cogs are rising up against the machine.

Comment: Cogs of the machine makes me think of government bureaucrats.

Answer (score 19):

The [Proles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proles).

The [Peons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peon).

The subjects, the constituents, the electorate, or, according to a certain lighthearted author (not me) - the refuse of history.

Comment: Note that "Prole" is clearly intended to associate with "proletariat:.

Answer (score 8):

The [**People**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/people?s=t)

Dictionary.com Definition:

> noun
>
> the ordinary persons, as distinguished from those who have wealth, rank, influence, etc.

"a man of the people"

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to "the Man", you have "the little guy".

Comment: I think "the little people" would be more appropriate in context.

Comment: "Little People" has the connotation of fairies, etc.

Answer (score 6):

A specifically derogatory term is **riffraff**. Especially used for the lower classes:

> **riffraff**
>
> the lowest classes; rabble:
> *the riffraff of the city.*

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/riffraff)

Answer (score 5):

***The underdog***

> *Slang* A person or ​group of ​people with less ​power, ​money, etc. than the ​rest of ​society: *As a ​politician, her ​sympathy was always for the underdog in ​society*. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/underdog)

***The rabble***

> 1. People of a ​low ​social ​position:
>      *Her ​speech ​stirred the ​emotions of the rabble*. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/rabble)
> 2. (*Metallurgy*) An iron tool or mechanical device for stirring, mixing, or skimming a molten charge in a roasting furnace [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rabble)
>
> [C17: from French râble, from Latin rutābulum rake for a furnace, from ruere to rake, dig up]

Answer (score 5):

(The) Hoi polloi: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hoi-polloi)

The masses or common people.

Comment: Ironically, this word sounds so "hoity-toity" that I've run into people who think it refers to the elites, rather than to the masses.

Comment: Those people need re-educating :)

Comment: I try, but frequently am told that words mean what people who use them think they mean, which is quite depressing.  In a case like this, by taking on a meaning opposite its original meaning, the word literally becomes meaningless.

Comment: To be pedantic: the "hoi" is the article, so one wouldn't say "the hoi polloi". In English of course, that's exactly what we do say. Oh, and the contrast is *hoi oligoi* or "the few".

Comment: @Sam Wilson Yes, sadly a lot of people do say it though!

Comment: @MontyHarder, I agree. _Hoi polloi_ is reminiscent of _hoity-toity_, and these have opposite senses. If a word doesn't mean what it sounds like it ought to mean, then it is a bad word in my opinion. (If people think that bare sounds themselves can't convey meanings, then they should look up the "bouba / kiki effect".) Another bad word is _pulchritude_ for this reason.

Comment: @dangph Part of the reason I asked whether the interest were in what these people call themselves.  The people who use the term "Hoi polloi" do not think themselves members of that group. Similarly, people who say "hoity-toity" are never describing themselves; they're talking about people who have learned to use Greek terms like "hoi polloi" and are therefore "hoity-toity", as most folks find speaking proper English to be "putting on airs".

Answer (score 2):

The **great unwashed**.

> **great unwashed** *pl ‎(plural only)*
>
> - *(idiomatic)* A contemptuous term for the populace, particularly the working class.
>
> <sub><sup>Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/great_unwashed)</sup></sub>

IMO, the contempt mirrors the hostility shown by phrases such as *the machine*.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, I think "the sheep" could work.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'the [drones](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drone)' would be accurate in this analogy - "A person who does tedious or menial work; a drudge"

Or given that definition 'the [drudges](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drudge)' - "A person who does tedious, menial, or unpleasant work."

Answer (score 1):

If the machine in question is the war machine then the people would presumably correspond to *cannon fodder*.